# Policy iteration: Cost-to-go function and Q-factor difference?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am currently reading the "Neural Networks and learning Machines" by Simon Haykins book.
In chapter 12 on policy iteration I don't really see the two differences between the cost-to-go function and the Q-factor:

$J^{\mu_n}(i)= c(i,\mu_n(i)) + \gamma \sum_{j=1}^N p_{ij}(\mu_n(i))J^{\mu_n}(j)$

$Q^{\mu_n}(i,a)= c(i,a) + \gamma \sum_{j=1}^N p_{ij}(a)J^{\mu_n}(j)$

Where $a = \mu_n(i)$ all according to the book.

To me both functions are really saying and doing the exact same thing. 
I understand that $a$ is an additional variable of $Q$ but in essence since there is an individual J/Q for each $\mu_n$ both functions just do the same thing.Can someone help me out on what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a choice under policy $\mu_n$ then indeed you might express that as $a = \mu_n(i)$.

The Q-factor does not pre-suppose you will make the same choice as the policy on *the next step*, it allows you to evaluate the expected future cost for taking *any* action (and from that point on following $\mu_n$).

Differences between $Q$ and $J$ therefore allow you to select a different $a$ in next iteration of the policy.